# Dcast in R basis repeated

Tags: r

I have data named as my_data. The amount of data is > 100000. Sample output is like below

```
id                      source
    8166923397733625478 happimobiles
    8166923397733625478 Springfit
    7301100145962413274 Duroflex
    6703062895304712434 happimobiles
    6897156268457025524 themrphone
    37564799155342281   Sangeetha Mobiles
    1159098248970201145 Sangeetha Mobiles
```

I used the code below and also table(my_data).

```
library("readxl")
my_data <- read_excel("C:\\Users\\ashishpatodia\\Desktop\\R\\Code\\Sample_Data_Overlap.xlsx",sheet = "10000 sample")

setDT(my_data)
(cohorts <- dcast(unique(my_data)[,cohort:=(source),by=id],cohort~ source, fun.aggregate=length, value.var="cohort"))
```

I want output where every id should be counted under source and also under which that is repeated
Ex ID ending with 5478 falls under both happimobiles and springfit. So happimobiles has id 8166923397733625478 and 6703062895304712434  which makes it 2 and 1 is common with springfit.

Output

```
                   happimobiles   Springfit  Duroflex themrphone   Sangeetha    
happimobiles         2                1        0          0            0
Springfit            1                1        0          0            0
Duroflex             0                0        1          0            0  
themrphone           0                0        0          1            0
Sangeetha            0                0        0          0            1
```

I have also tried

```
Pivot<-dcast(my_data,source~source,value.var = "id",function(x) length((x)))
```

which is giving me only unique records in specific partner correctly but not overlaps.

I also tried

```
crossprod(table(my_data))
```

But this doesnot give correct answer

Link to entire data

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HUoRlVVf8EBedj1puXdgtTS6GGeFsXYqjVicUwbc5KE/edit#gid=0 for which i want the code to run

Comment: No just using table(my_data) helps. My output should be like i mentioned

Comment: Yes but not good to stereotype...what makes it cool to say 0.1 million.. do not forget we invented zero

Answer (score 1):

We can use `table` with `crossprod` from `base R`

```
crossprod(table(my_data))
#            source
#source              Duroflex happimobiles Sangeetha Mobiles Springfit themrphone
#  Duroflex                 1            0                 0         0          0
#  happimobiles             0            2                 0         1          0
#  Sangeetha Mobiles        0            0                 2         0          0
#  Springfit                0            1                 0         1          0
#  themrphone               0            0                 0         0          1
```

#### data

```
my_data <- structure(list(id = c(8166923397733625856, 8166923397733625856, 
7301100145962413056, 6703062895304712192, 6897156268457025536, 
37564799155342280, 1159098248970201088), source = c("happimobiles", 
"Springfit", "Duroflex", "happimobiles", "themrphone", "Sangeetha Mobiles", 
"Sangeetha Mobiles")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Will the code change if I have a month column as well.  If i want to calculate month on month then

Comment: @ashishpat  One option if we want to use the same method is `lapply(split(my_data[c("id", "source")], my_data$month), function(x) crossprod(table(x)))`

Comment: Hello akrun my data is giving me wrong output I have edited the question

Comment: @ashishpat  Based on the data you showed, it is giving the correct output

Comment: akrun agreed...I tested on the above and it gives me exactly what I wanted. When I run this on 10000 records I am getting worng result. Is it because of data type or some other issue as I am unable to debug.

Comment: @ashishpat  Can you please show a small example where you find this anomaly.  Then, it would be easier to test

Comment: Output shoes 70K+ for one soource wherease I have 10k rows. Shall I share the entire data. How to share the entire data here. Cant copy paste. Also no git. Any other way. Shall I share Google Spreadsheet Link if you share your email id